golang tgbotapi как получить определенную информацию о пользователе?
Создаю телеграмм чат-бота. Застрял на нескольких моментах:

Как узнать статус пользователя? Мне нужно узнать, является ли пользователь администратором. Эта информация хранится в структуре ChatMember, но статус при ее создании приходится прописывать самому, в виду чего вся затея проваливается

Как с помощью ввода userName (@randomUser) пользователя получить полную структуру User касательно него, либо же просто его ID (611222111)?



Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Подскажите пожалуйста, где именно мой вопрос оформлен неправильно?

Попробуйте немного точнее описать задачу и добавить пример кода/trace ошибки с проблемным местом — так ответ найдется быстрее! А ссылка на справку — просто для ориентира: там советы, которые помогут быстрее получить полезный ответ и облегчить задачу тем, кто старается вам помочь.

Вот это не оно?
